# bootstrap 2 input-append add-on

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using bootstrap input-append add-on to add a icon to the end of the input field. This all works nicely. The issue is setting a width of 100% on the input pushes the add-on span tag outside the parents "input-wrapper" div viewable area. 
I'm using box-sizing: border-box; on all input fields.
the only way I can seem to make this work is setting the parent div "input-wrapper" to display: flex; Unfortunately this is not an option as it's not supported in IE8 or 9. What other options do I have.

http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/zjx2zc6e/

Example code.

```
        <div id="form-elements">
        <div class="input-wrapper input-append">
            <input id="paymentDate" class='paymentDate' type="text" />
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE

```
    #form-elements{
        margin: 20px;
    }

   input[type]{
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-height: 30px;
   }

    #paymentDate{
     height: 30px;
     width: 100%;
    }

    .input-wrapper{
        width: 600px;
        border: 1px dashed red;
    }
```

Comment: Added a Jsfiddle url showing the issue where the span tag is smashed outside the parent divs width and border boundary.

Comment: v2.1.0?! You should at least upgrade to v2.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: My bad, on Bootstrap2 there was an issue with the "input-block-level" feature working with addons (it works for all other inputs). A few people came up with some workarounds, mainly using a table display. You can see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/BMironov/BVmUL/

Here is the CSS that handles it - you may want to play around with the way the add-on span works.

```
.input-append.input-block-level {
  display: table; 
}
.input-append.input-block-level .add-on {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 16px;
}
.input-append.input-block-level > input {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  display: table;
  min-height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-append.input-block-level > input {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

Instead of setting the input to 100% width, add the class `input-block-level` to the text input. You shouldn't need any additional CSS, that functionality is built into Bootstrap 2.

Comment: I added input-block-level to the input tag but it didn't fix the issue. See jsfiddle link in the post to test it out.

Comment: I fixed it - I completely forgot that there was an issue with input-block-level with addons that needed to be manually fixed. input-block-level worked with everything else though!

Answer (score -1):

It's obvious that if one of your nested element `input` is set with 100% width, your other nested element `span` will get outside the wrapper, which total width is being occupied by `input`.

Comment: Yes it is obvious, that's why my question asks for a solution to this problem.

Comment: There is not problem. That's the expected behaviour. If you want to wrap 2 elements, one of them shouldn't ocuppied the 100% of the wrapper available area.